# Led bar indicator flickering within adjacent values and how to avoid this (embedded-C)

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, stm32

I am designing a measurement instrument that has a visible user output on a 30-LEDs bar. The program logic acts in this fashion (pseudo-code)

```
while(1)
{
 (1)Sensor_Read();
 (2)Transform_counts_into_leds();
 (3)Send_to_bar();
{
```

The relevant function (2) is a simple algorithm that transforms the counts from the I2C sensor to a value serially sent to shift-registers that control the single leds.
The variable sent to function (3) is simply the number of LEDs that have to stay on (0 for al LEDs off, 30 for all LEDs on)

```
uint8_t Transform_counts_into_leds(uint16_t counts)
{
 float on_leds;
 on_leds = (uint8_t)(counts * 0.134);    /*0.134 is a dummy value*/
 return on_leds;
}
```

*using this program logic when counts value is on the threshold between two LEDs, the next led flickers*

I think this is a bad user experience for my device and I want the LEDs, once lit, to stay stable in a small range of values.

**QUESTION: How a solution to this problem could be implemented in my project?**

Comment: Post the code, not images of it.....

Comment: You should start studying something about [digital filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter)

Comment: [Moving Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) can be be an idea.

Comment: Rather than hysteresis you can just slow the loop down, e.g. sleep for 250 ms on each iteration.

Comment: I wouldn't bother, just limit the refresh rate and clock through the shift register as quickly as possible. At, say, a 100 kHz clock and a 4 Hz update the flicker won't be perceptible to the eye. Take care to avoid interrupts mid-update though, using hardware peripherals if you can. Granted if the data is jittery then you might still want to filter for the benefit of the user, though that is a different issue.

Comment: You may still need to implement hysteresis even when you use a filter. When the current bar changes by only one unit, record a time stamp of some kind, and ensure the proposed bar changes for long enough before actually displaying that change. It is rather like keypress debouncing, but applied to output.

Comment: Apart from the mistyped variable names and the fact that `on_leds` should be `uint8_t` rather than `float`, avoid using floating point unless you really need it - especially on a target with no FPU.  It adds a lot of code and will be relatively slow.  Rather than `on_leds = (uint8_t)(counts * 0.134);`, use `on_leds = (uint8_t)((counts * 134) / 1000 ) ;`, or an even more efficient approximation; `on_leds = (uint8_t)((counts * 137) >> 10 ) ;` (137/1024 = 0.1338).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out about mistyped variable. I just fixed it.

Comment: You have presented an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), you have decided that the solution is to use hysteresis, and asked how to do that.  In this case you have also described the real problem - you should have left it at that - hysteresis may have been one of the answers, but there are other possibilities that you have excluded by asking a question about the solution rather then the problem.

Comment: I will edit the question to make easier presenting other solutions by the users

Comment: Regarding my earlier comment, the transformation you need is simply `on_leds = (LED_MAX * counts) / MAX_COUNTS ;`.  Where `LED_MAX` is the number of LEDs present, and `MAX_COUNTS` is the maximum possible value of `counts`.  No need to make a simple thing complicated.

Comment: @Clifford: Filtering will not remove all flickering, because it does not eliminate the possibility of the average being at the middle between two display values. Each update of the average may ping-pong the average from one display value to the other. (I've commented further about this under your answer.) Hysteresis, however, can eliminate the flicker; and, if applied to the display value at higher precision (i.e., before scaling it down, before the division), you can still display the accurate value (i.e. at most half an unit of error to the displayed value).

Answer (score 3):

Hysteresis is useful for a number of applications, but I would suggest not appropriate in this instance.  The problem is that if the level genuinely falls from say 8 to 7 for example you would not see any change until at least one sample at 6 and it would jump to 6 and there would have to be a sample of 8 before it went back to 7.

A more appropriate solution in the case is a moving average, although it is simpler and more useful to use a *moving sum* and use the higher resolution that gives.  For example a moving-sum of 16 effectively adds (almost) 4 bits of resolution, making a 8 bit sensor effectively 12 bit - at the cost of bandwidth of course; you don't get something for nothing.  In this case lower bandwidth (i.e. less responsive to higher frequencies is *exactly* what you need)

Moving sum:

```
#define BUFFER_LEN 16 ;
#define SUM_MAX (255 * BUFFER_LEN)
#define LED_MAX 30

uint8_t buffer[BUFFER_LEN] = {0} ;
int index = 0 ;
uint16_t sum = 0 ;

for(;;)
{
    uint8_t sample = Sensor_Read() ;

    // Maintain sum of buffered values by 
    // subtracting oldest buffered value and 
    // adding the new sample
    sum -= buffer[index] ;              
    sum += sample ;

    // Replace oldest sample with new sample 
    // and increment index to next oldest sample
    buffer[index] = sample ;
    index = (index + 1) % BUFFER_LEN ;

    // Transform to LED bar level
    int led_level = (LED_MAX * sum) / SUM_MAX ;

    // Show level
    setLedBar( led_level ) ;
}
```

Comment: Your comment about hysteresis is only valid if applied to the display value at display precision. In my answer, I attempt to describe why, and how, it should be applied to a higher-precision intermediate value (say, `sum` in your above code), in which case it can eliminate the flicker (for a value in the middle of two display states) without introducing error in the displayed value. Also, I do claim filtering (moving average or exponential smoothing) serves a different purpose -- dealing with sensor/measurement noise --, and does not necessarily even eliminate display flicker.

Comment: Consider, for example, a relatively noise-free sensor, say a DS18B20 (±0.5°C). Let's say the sensor is in free air, with air temperature exactly at say 19.75°C. Some of the readings will be 19.5°C, and some 20.0°C. If the output uses one bar per 1°C, averaging will not remove the flicker, because each reading (sensor update) may change the average from ≥20°C to ≤20°C or vice versa (and it does not matter how large/long the filter is). Filtering does not remove the knife edge change of the displayed value, in other words.

Comment: @NominalAnimal : Good point about the hysteresis implementation; your answer applies.  By reducing the bandwidth and therefore the speed at which the value can change, a moving average (or any form of low-pass filtering for that matter) would achieve the desired result - the level may still of course switch between two values, but only when that is the low frequency trend rather then just noise - the question of when "flicker" become "wanted signal" is application dependent and in this method can be determined by appropriate buffer length.

Comment: True. I do think that your solution works fine in practice, especially if experimentally tuned to work with a specific sensor! Other than hysteresis not being applicable here, I have no issues with your answer. :) I do strongly differentiate between filtering (and only apply it to suppress sensor noise) and display value hysteresis (which I consider an user interface feature, removing information -- smaller than half-an-ULP changes -- that may be distracting to the observer). Rereading my comments above, I think me fail English: incorrect tone. I ...

Comment: I only intended to point out only that one point that I disagreed with (hysteresis being applicable to this problem), while otherwise agreeing with your answer (and filtering being useful in general), plus maybe that  I've found the differentiation between filtering and hysteresis very useful in practice, but as usual, I verbosed off.. Yup, me fail English.

Comment: @NominalAnimal : On reflection you are entirely right.  I have taken no offence, and your English is exemplary.  I am considering deleting this answer, but I'll let it stand for a while.  It may not answer the question, but may serve some purpose.

Comment: Yes, I think it is better to let it stand -- the example code is quite good; for example, you only use one addition and one subtraction per sample, whereas mine sums over the entire array every time (which I also do in real code, of course) -- so I too would prefer it to stay. Also, I'm glad you didn't take offense, because I definitely intended none. Face-to-face communication is easier, because there are so many additional cues (especially facial expressions). Technical writing is easy; tone and emotional intent hard to convey.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying problem -- displaying sensor data in a human-friendly way -- is very interesting. Here's my approach in pseudocode:

```
Loop:

    Read sensor
    If sensor outside valid range:
        Enable warning LED
        Sleep in a low-power state for a while
        Restart loop            
    Else:
        Disable warning LED

    Filter sensor value

    Compute display value from sensor value with extra precision:
        If new display value differs sufficiently from current value:
            Update current displayed value

    Update display with scaled-down display value
```

Filtering deals with noise in the measurements. Filtering smoothes out any sudden changes in the measurement, removing sudden spikes. It is like erosion, turning sharp and jagged mountains into rolling fells and hills.

Hysteresis hides small changes, but does not otherwise filter the results. Hysteresis won't affect noisy or jagged data, it only hides small changes.

Thus, the two are separate, but complementary methods, that affect the readout in different ways.

Below, I shall describe two different filters, and two variants of simple hysteresis implementation suitable for numeric and bar graph displays.

If possible, I'd recommend you write some scripts or test programs that output the input data and the variously filtered output data, and plot it in your favourite plotting program (mine is Gnuplot). Or, better yet, experiment! Nothing beats practical experiments for human interface stuff (at least if you use existing suggestions and known theory as your basis, and leap forward from there).

---

[Moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average):

You create an array of `N` sensor readings, updating them in a round-robin fashion, and using their average as the current reading. This produces very nice (as in human-friendly, intuitive) results, as only the `N` latest sensor readings affect the average.

When the application is first started, you should copy the very first reading into all `N` entries in the averaging array. For example:

```
#define  SENSOR_READINGS  32

int sensor_reading[SENSOR_READINGS];
int sensor_reading_index;

void sensor_init(const int reading)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < SENSOR_READINGS; i++)
        sensor_reading[i] = reading;

    sensor_reading_index = 0;
}

int sensor_update(const int reading)
{
    int i, sum;

    sensor_reading_index = (sensor_reading_index + 1) % SENSOR_READINGS;
    sensor_reading[sensor_reading_index] = reading;

    sum = sensor_reading[0];
    for (i = 1; i < SENSOR_READINGS; i++)
        sum += sensor_reading[i];

    return sum / SENSOR_READINGS;
}
```

At start-up, you call `sensor_init()` with the very first valid sensor reading, and `sensor_update()` with the following sensor readings. The `sensor_update()` will return the filtered result.

The above works best when the sensor is regularly polled, and `SENSOR_READINGS` can be chosen large enough to properly filter out any unwanted noise in the sensor readings. Of course, the array requires RAM, which may be on short supply in some microcontrollers.

---

[Exponential smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing):

When there is not enough RAM to use a moving average to filter data, an exponential smoothing filter is often applied.

The idea is that we keep an average value, and recalculate the average using each new sensor reading using `(A * average + B * reading) / (A + B)`. The effect of each sensor reading on the average decays exponentially: the weight of the most current sensor reading is always `B/(A+B)`, the weight of the previous one is `A*B/(A+B)^2`, the weight of the one before that is `A^2*B/(A+B)^3`, and so on (`^` indicating exponentiation); the weight of the `n`'th sensor reading in the past (with current one being `n=0`) is `A^n*B/(A+B)^(n+1)`.

The code corresponding to the previous filter is now

```
#define SENSOR_AVERAGE_WEIGHT 31
#define SENSOR_CURRENT_WEIGHT  1

int sensor_reading;

void sensor_init(const int reading)
{
    sensor_reading = reading;
}

int sensor_update(const int reading)
    return sensor_reading = (sensor_reading * SENSOR_AVERAGE_WEIGHT +
                             reading * SENSOR_CURRENT_WEIGHT) /
                            (SENSOR_AVERAGE_WEIGHT + SENSOR_CURRENT_WEIGHT);
}
```

Note that if you choose the weights so that their sum is a power of two, most compilers optimize the division into a simple bit shift.

---

Applying hysteresis:

(This section, including example code, edited on 2016-12-22 for clarity.)

Proper hysteresis support involves having the displayed value in higher precision than is used for output. Otherwise, your output value with hysteresis applied will never change by a single unit, which I would consider a bad design in an user interface. (I'd much prefer a value to flicker between two consecutive values every few seconds, to be honest -- and that's what I see in e.g. the weather stations I like best with good temperature sensors.)

There are two typical variants in how hysteresis is applied to readouts: fixed, and dynamic. Fixed hysteresis means that the displayed value is updated whenever the value differs by a fixed limit; dynamic means the limits are set dynamically. (The dynamic hysteresis is much rarer, but it may be very useful when coupled with the moving average; one can use the standard deviation (or error bars) to set the hysteresis limits, or set asymmetric limits depending on whether the new value is smaller or greater than the previous one.)

The fixed hysteresis is very simple to implement. First, because we need to apply the hysteresis to a higher-precision value than the output, we choose a suitable multiplier. That is, `display_value = value / DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER`, where `value` is the possibly filtered sensor value, and `display_value` is the integer value displayed (number of bars lit, for example).

Note that below, `display_value` and the value returned by the functions, refer to the integer value displayed, for example the number of lit LED bars. `value` is the (possibly filtered) sensor reading, and `saved_value` containing the sensor reading that is currently displayed.

```
#define DISPLAY_HYSTERESIS 10
#define DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER 32

int saved_value;

void display_init(const int value)
{
    saved_value = value;
}

int display_update(const int value)
{
    const int delta = value - saved_value;
    if (delta < -DISPLAY_HYSTERESIS ||
        delta >  DISPLAY_HYSTERESIS)
        saved_value = value;
    return saved_value / DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER;
}
```

The `delta` is just the difference between the new sensor value, and the sensor value corresponding to the currently displayed value.

The effective hysteresis, in units of displayed value, is `DISPLAY_HYSTERESIS/DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER = 10/32 = 0.3125` here. It means that the displayed value can be updated three times before a visible change is seen (if e.g. slowly decreasing or increasing; more if the value is just fluctuating, of course). This eliminates rapid flickering between two visible values (when the value is in the middle of two displayed values), but ensures the error of the reading is less than half display units (on average; half plus effective hysteresis in the worst case).

In a real life application, you usually use a more complete form `return (saved_value * DISPLAY_SCALE + DISPLAY_OFFSET) / DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER`, which scales the filtered sensor value by `DISPLAY_SCALE`/`DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER` and moves the zero point by `DISPLAY_OFFSET`/`DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER`, both evaluated at `1.0/DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER` precision, but only using integer operations. However, for simplicity, I'll just assume that to derive the display value `value`, say the number of lit LED bars, you just divide the sensor value by `DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER`. In either case, the hysteresis is `DISPLAY_HYSTERESIS`/`DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER` of the output unit. Ratios of about 0.1 to 0.5 work fine; and the below test values, `10` and `32`, yields 0.3125, which is about midway of the range of ratios that I believe work best.

Dynamic hysteresis is very similar to above:

```
#define DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER 32

int saved_value_below;
int saved_value;
int saved_value_above;

void display_init(const int value, const int below, const int above)
{
    saved_value_below = below;
    saved_value = value;
    saved_value_above = above;
}

int display_update(const int value, const int below, const int above)
{
    if (value < saved_value - saved_value_below ||
        value > saved_value + saved_value_above) {
        saved_value_below = below;
        saved_value = value;
        saved_value_above = above;
    }
    return saved_value / DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER;
}
```

Note that if `DISPLAY_HYSTERESIS*2 <= DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER`, the displayed value is always within a display unit of the actual (filtered) sensor value. In other words, hysteresis can easily deal with flickering, but it does not need to add much error to the displayed value.

In many practical cases the best amount of hysteresis applied depends on the amount of short-term variations in the sensor samples. This includes not only noise, but also the types of signals that are to be measured. A hysteresis of just 0.3 (relative to the output unit) is sufficient to completely eliminate the flicker when sensor readings flip the filtered sensor value between two consecutive integers that map to different integer ouputs, as it ensures that the filtered sensor value must change by at least 0.3 (in output display units) before it effects a change in the display.

The maximum error with hysteresis is half display units plus the current hysteresis. The half unit is the minimum error possible (since consecutive units are one unit apart, so when the true value is in the middle, either value shown is correct to within half a unit). With dynamic hysteresis, if you always start with some fixed hysteresis value when a reading changes enough, but when the reading is within the hysteresis, you instead just decrease the hysteresis (if greater than zero). This approach leads to a changing sensor value being tracked correctly (maximum error being half an unit plus the initial hysteresis), but a relatively static value being displayed as accurately as possible (at half an unit maximum error). I don't show an example of this, because it adds another tunable (how the hysteresis decays towards zero), and requires that you verify (calibrate) the sensor (including any filtering) first; otherwise it's like polishing a turd: possible, but not useful.

Also note that if you have 30 bars in the display, you actually have 31 states (zero bars, one bar, .., 30 bars), and thus the proper range for the `value` is `0` to `31*DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER - 1`, inclusive.

Comment: Very exaustive answer.

Comment: Many thanks for your exhaustive reply. I used moving average in the past for an instruments that used 7-segments interface for output. In that case the smoothing produced the required effect of a soft transition between values. Btw I never used hysteresis so I kindly ask if you can include some comments in the hysteresis examples to make it more clear (I did not fully understand what `const int value` is and `DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER` is used for)

Comment: @danstm: Could you please re-read the *"Applying hysteresis:"* section? I heavily edited it, renamed a couple of variables in the examples, and describe their meaning/use in the text; I'd like to know if it makes more sense, or whether I need to rewrite that part to explain it better. In short, `value` is the filtered sensor reading, `saved_value` is the filtered sensor reading that is currently displayed, and the return value from the functions is the integer value displayed. `DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER` is a simple scale factor: *displayed_value* = *sensor_value* / `DISPLAY_MULTIPLIER`.